# Como usar Highlight <button onclick=...>

Tags: javascript

Estou procurando a forma de deixar um botão que já venha selecionado ao abrir da pagina, ou que seja selecionado posteriormente, visível. Ou melhor, com highlight.

Deixarei abaixo o código que estou usando, consigo trocar entre uma div e outra perfeitamente, e a div inicial é a id="balances", esta sempre aparecerá ativa quando a página for aberta... Gostaria de deixar tanto o botão que da call na div incial, quanto os outros em highlight quando selecionados...

É possivel? Com href"#" eu sei que da certo, mas com onclick não estou conseguindo achar a solução, e nesse caso, precisará ser onclick...

```js
function show(elementID) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
  if (!ele) {
    alert("no such element");
    return;
  }
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('big-one');
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  ele.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="admix">
  <div class="topox"><h class="topotext">TITLE TOPO</h></div>
  <!--refazer bordas-->
  <div class="admenus">
    <button class=admenus1 onclick="show('balances');"> Balances </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onclick="show('stats');"> Stats </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onclick="show('configs');"> Configurations </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onclick="show('pagez');"> Page </button>
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="balances">
    inside balances div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="stats"  style="display:none">
    inside stats div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="configs" style="display:none">
    inside config div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="pagez" style="display:none">
    inside page div
  </div>
</div>
```

Não consigo deixar esse onclick com highlight de maneira alguma... nem quando ao abrir  da página, nem ao clicar depois. Mas as divs estão abrindo normalmente quando chamadas.
Alguma Luz?

Valeu! :D

Comment: Pode ser com CSS?

Comment: Claro, Victor! Pode sim, nenhum problema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quisesse apenas que o botão mantenha a seleção se não clicasse em mais nada o código seria esse:

Usei funções `On` nas divs e podem ser adicionadas outras caso haja a necessidade, vou mostrar o `code` pronto e depois explicarei as funções.

```js
function show(elementID) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
  if (!ele) {
    alert("no such element");
    return;
  }
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('big-one');
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  ele.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="admix">
  <div class="topox"><h class="topotext">TITLE TOPO</h></div>
  <!--refazer bordas-->
  <div class="admenus">
    <button class=admenus1 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0';" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';" onclick="show('balances');"> Balances </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0';" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';" onclick="show('stats');"> Stats </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0';" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';" onclick="show('configs');"> Configurations </button>
    <button class=admenus1 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0';" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';" onclick="show('pagez');"> Page </button>
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="balances">
    inside balances div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="stats"  style="display:none">
    inside stats div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="configs" style="display:none">
    inside config div
  </div>

  <div class="big-one" id="pagez" style="display:none">
    inside page div
  </div>
</div>
```

O que temos são funções `OnFocus` e `OnBlur`, agora o que cada uma faz?

`OnFocus` trabalha com a seleção, ou seja, no clique e a funçao `OnBlur` trabalha com o "mouse out" ou seja, saída do mouse, o desfoque do mouse, clicando em uma área fora da div ou do button no caso.

Deixando claro que, o `button` muda sua cor após o `OnBlur` por ter sua cor modificada pela função, caso for usar `CSS` pode usar normalmente na função.

Agora para manter a seleção até selecionar outro butão, ou seja, ele ficará selecionado mesmo clicando fora da div, clicando em outra página, ele só irá tirar a seleção caso selecionado outra aba.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.tabs-menu {
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.tabs-menu li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}
.tabs-menu li.current {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}
.tabs-menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs-menu .current a {
  color: #2e7da3;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto;
}
.tab-content {
  width: 660px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
#tab-1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="admix">
  <div class="topox">
    <h class="topotext">TITLE TOPO</h>
  </div>
  <!--refazer bordas-->
  <div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
      <li> <a href="#tab-1">Balances </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-2">Stats </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-3">Configurations </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-4">Page</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        inside balances div
      </div>

      <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        inside stats div
      </div>

      <div class="big-one" id="configs" style="display:none">
        inside config div
      </div>

      <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        inside page div
      </div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        inside some div
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Por problemas no snippet do Stack você pode ver funcionando neste [exemplo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5156/)

Comment: Cara, a ideia é exatamente essa!
O único problema, é o fato de quando clica fora do botão, mesmo que seja na div que ele está dando call, o highlight some...
Tipo, você acaba perdendo a "noção" da aba(button) que está sendo acessada.

Comment: Agora acredito que eu entendi, você quer que o botão se mantenha selecionado ao clicar na div ou fora do botão mas ao clicar em outro botão , apenas o novo fique selecionado e o antigo perca a seleção certo?

Comment: Opa, desculpe a demora!
Exatamente isso, Victor!

Como se o botão fosse um "botão de menu" que quando você entra na página, no caso a div, o botão te informa a "div pagina" que você se encontra. :D

Sou razoavelmente leigo na hora de customizar um visual mais atrativo, por isso estou penando! hahah

Comment: Editei a resposta, verifique o novo exemplo ;)

Comment: Wow! 100% Man! Era isso mesmo! Muitíssimo obrigado!
Agora meu adm panel vai ficar showwww! hahah
Valeu, Victor! :D

Answer (score 0):

você não conseguir aplicar um estilo `:visited` à um elemento do tipo `button`.

O que você pode fazer, é criar uma classe no css para estilizar um `button.admenus1` que já foi clicado.

Então você deverá armazenar no localStorage alguma informação que identifique que o `button` foi clicado, então ao carregar a pagina você recupera esta informação.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-show]");
var current = document.querySelector(".big-one.show");
    
[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button, indice) {
  var bigOne = document.getElementById(button.dataset.show);  
  var seletor = "'[data-show='" + button.dataset.show + "']";  
  if (localStorage.getItem(seletor) === "true") {
    button.classList.add("visited");
  }  
  if (bigOne) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {      
      localStorage.setItem(seletor, "true");
      button.classList.add("visited");
      current.classList.remove("show");
      current = bigOne;
      current.classList.add("show");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.admenus1.visited {
  color: purple;
}

.big-one {
  display: none;
}

.big-one.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="admix">
  <div class="topox"><h class="topotext">TITLE TOPO</h></div>
  <!--refazer bordas-->
  <div class="admenus">
    <button class="admenus1" data-show="balances"> Balances </button>
    <button class="admenus1" data-show="stats"> Stats </button>
    <button class="admenus1" data-show="configs"> Configurations </button>
    <button class="admenus1" data-show="pagez"> Page </button>
  </div>
  <div class="big-one show" id="balances">
    inside balances div
  </div>
  <div class="big-one" id="stats">
    inside stats div
  </div>
  <div class="big-one" id="configs">
    inside config div
  </div>
  <div class="big-one" id="pagez">
    inside page div
  </div>
</div>
```

devido a uma limitação do Snippet do SO, o exemplo acima não vai funcionar.
Você pode ver o mesmo exemplo funcionando no seguinte [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2773a72/)

Comment: O ruim do :visited, é que continua após a seleção de outro button, fazendo que todos fiquem iguais.

Comment: Olá, boa noite! Valeu a atenção fera!

Correria, só deu tempo de testar agora há pouco...

Então, os botoes já estavam sendo definidos pelo css, apenas adicionei as linhas que você indiciou, mas acho que não rodou 100% aqui também. 
Reparei que o "display: none" para a div big-one estava fazendo com que nenhuma aba aparecesse ativa quando a página era carregada. Acabava sendo necessário clicar primeiro, para ai sim o conteúdo da div aparecer... Removi o display e funcionou como o script anterior, apenas mudando a "aba", mas sem conseguir destacar qual aba estava sendo acessada.